# Is it better to add to style.css or create your own css when using a template?

Tags: css

I downloaded an HTML website template and converted it to a wordpress theme. I know wordpress requires a file called style.css (which came with my template). If I want to make my own custom styling in my wordpress site, is it best practice to just edit the style.css file? Or to create my own css file and add it in functions.php?

I know there's also a section in the wordpress editor to add custom lines of css but that seems dangerous to me as I don't know where it's putting that code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solely depends on you. You can go with both the options. As you are developing the custom wordpress theme from scratch you can add the code into themes default style.css.

If you are using any another css file the better way to do it is to insert it directly into the header file in place of calling it via hook in functions.php.